# View of Taxonomy with titles above the terms

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms

Does anyone know if I have a view of a Taxonomy Vocabulary - How do I get titles above all the term results?  Here is my page:
`http://64.34.70.141/~henryl/bloom-size`
I'd like to have titles like this website:
http://demo.commerceguys.com/ck/collection/drink
But I can't figure out how they've added the titles - I've tried to look through the view selections of the site but I can't get mine to match.
Can anyone help?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an unformatted list view of node teasers. Just click Format settings on view edit page, and turn on Force using fields. After that this result will be shown as teaser, but you can add fields.

Add your taxonomy term field to the Fields, and you can use it in Format settings Grouping field Nr.1. If the teaser doesn't contains this field, you have to add a relationship to the proper taxonomy term too.

Comment: Thanks for helping.  I'm close - I've been able to get the headings but I can't get the image to come in for some reason.  I've tried every image content, field etc. but none of them bring the image into the page.  Here's what it looks like.  http://64.34.70.141/~henryl/bloom-size